# Rich Faces Tree Control for handheld device

Tags: jsf, jboss, tree

Currently I have a rich tree which works as expected; however the tree itself is not appropriate for small devices where you use your finger for navigation.  The arrow that represents the child nodes, and their expansion, is too small.  Is there any way to change that graphic, or increase its size?

Answer (score 0):

Try the icon attribute of the treeNode

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I have to change the style of rich-tree-node-handleicon-expanded and rich-tree-node-handleicon-collapsed.

.rich-tree-node-handleicon-expanded {
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  }

.rich-tree-node-handleicon-collapsed {
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

Comment: Did this solve it? It looks like it should. You can find all the information you need about editing the css here: http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossrichfaces/freezone/docs/devguide/en/html/tree.html